# Javascript - Array.prototype.forEach() - are the three arguments necessary?

Tags: javascript

[Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) states:

> [the forEach callback] is invoked with three arguments:
>
> - the element value
> - the element index
> - the array being traversed

However, this is a little unclear to me. Are all three of these arguments necessary? The specific callback I'm writing will not use any of those values. Do I declare them anyway, or can I safely skip them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely skip them.

You never HAVE to declare function arguments. Often, values will be passed to callbacks whether or not you've prepared the callbacks to receive them - it matters only if your function needs to make use of those arguments.

An example is any event callback, e.g., to which the event object - reporting about what happened - is always passed as the first argument.

```
foo.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    //if I never reference the evt object, I need not define the evt argument
}, false);
```

Comment: While this is true for most callbacks, there are libraries that determine the type of callback based on the number of arguments the callback function defines. E.g. the error handling callbacks of the [express library](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Comment: This is true - however it's outside the conventions of native JavaScript, which has no equivalent of this behaviour. For vanilla JS, it's true to say callback arguments can be defined or not depending on usage.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most of the languages, javascript doesn't perform any check on the number of arguments with which a function is called. Since javascript callbacks are nothing but functions, this holds true for callbacks also.

```
function a(arg1){
  console.log(arg1);
}
```

function `a` can be invoked by

```
a(); // prints undefined
a(1); // prints 1
a(1,2); // prints 1
```

or with any number of arguments.

If a function is invoke with lesser number of argument than in the definition, the missing parameters are set to `undefined`.

All the arguments with which a function is called are available as a local variable `arguments`